# Nodejs Sequelize find with association

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

*A.js* :

```
A.associate = models => {
 A.hasMany(models.B, { foreignKey: 'A_id' });
 A.hasMany(models.C, { foreignKey: 'A_id' });
 A.hasMany(models.D, { foreignKey: 'A_id' });
};

A.findOne({
 where: { id: _id },
 include: [ B, C, D ],
});
```

*B.js* :

```
B.associate = models => {
 B.belongsTo(models.A, { foreignKey: 'A_id' });
};
```

*C.js* :

```
C.associate = models => {
 C.belongsTo(models.A, { foreignKey: 'A_id' });
};
```

*D.js* :

```
D.associate = models => {
 D.belongsTo(models.A, { foreignKey: 'A_id' });
};
```

*DB* :

```
A TABLE
 id:1 name: A
B TABLE
 A_id:1 name: B1
 A_id:1 name: B2
blabla...
```

*Result of A::findOne* :

```
A
 id:1 blabla...
B
 A_id:1 name: B1
 A_id:1 name: B2 -> NO FIND B2
```

I want to search 'single A record' and 'multiple B, C, D records'. How can I do this? **Association** in *Sequelize* is so confusing.

Any help is appreciated!

### @@@@@Source

*routes/A.js*

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  const { A } = require('../models');
  A.getById(req.params.id)
    .then(record => {
      console.log(record[0].Bs);
    });
});
```

*models/A.js*

```
A.associate = models => {
    A.belongsTo(models.User, {foreignKey: 'userId'});
    A.hasMany(models.B, {foreignKey: 'A_Id'});
    A.hasMany(models.C, {foreignKey: 'A_Id'});
  };

  A.getById = _id => {
    const { B, C } = require('../models');
    return A.findAll({
      where: { id: _id },
      include: [ B, C ],
    });
  };
```

*models/B.js*

```
B.associate = models => {
    B.belongsTo(models.A, { foreignKey: 'A_Id' });
  };
```

*executed Query*

```
SELECT `A`.`id`, `A`.`userId`, `A`.`name`,
`Bs`.`A_Id` AS `Bs.A_Id`, `Bs`.`name` AS `Bs.name`,
`Cs`.`A_Id` AS `Cs.A_Id`, `Cs`.`name` AS `Cs.name`
FROM `As` AS `A`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Bs` AS `Bs` ON `A`.`id` = `Bs`.`A_Id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Cs` AS `Cs` ON `A`.`id` = `Cs`.`A_Id`
WHERE `A`.`id` = '1'
```

*log in routes/A.js*

```
[ B {
  dataValues: { A_Id: 1, name: 'Name1' },
  _previousDataValues: ...
  ...
} ]
```

But results of executing query are multiple rows. (in DB client program)

Comment: Have you tried querying with `findAll()`? If you only have one record in A, it'll return that single record.. and it will return all other records from B, C and D

Comment: @legoMyEgo yes, I've tried it. But the results are same. single A, single B, C, D.

Comment: What is the exact code that executes your query? Add it to the question

Comment: @legoMyEgo thank you for comment. I added my source. please check my source. I cant solve this problem.